# Laravel Eloquent ORM returnig stdClass instead of actual Model

Tags: php, model, laravel, eloquent, stdclass

I'm doing

```
$mymodel = MyModel::where( 'url', $domain )->first();
```

and this was returning a MyModel object and now, somehow, it is returning a stdClass.

What's happening? Is it some update on the laravel? Have I changed something?

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, do you get as an `stdClass`, empty object ?

Comment: no. I get all the table fields on that stdClass.. But it should be a Model Object so I can access the methods that I have.. It was working fine but suddenly started only returning stdClass. I made an update to laravel today don't know if can be from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I did updated the laravel today and it was updating to a dev version.
By being dev it could have bugs and it did. I just rollback to version "4.1.22" and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue yesterday. But just updated again and it seems to have been fixed.