# Laravel - Dev version causes call to undefined method stdClass

Tags: laravel

I have the following function which activates a user after he registers via a url sent in email.

```
public function getActivate($code) {
    $user = User::where('code', '=', $code)->where('active', '=', 0);

    if($user->count()) {
        $user = $user->first();

        //Change user's active state 
        $user->active = 1;
        $user->code = '';

        if($user->save()) {
            return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'Activated! You can now sign in!');
        }
}
    return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('global', 'We could not activate your account. Try again later.');
}
```

This was working, but now all i get is this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to undefined method stdClass::save()
```

Comment: Is this latest `dev` version ? What is the exact version ?

Comment: Did you update `Laravel` recently ? If yes, then rollback, it's bug in the latest `dev` version. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22106845/741747).

Comment: I updated composer recently. Should i run composer self-update --rollback

Comment: That's it, it's a bug on the `dev` version.

Comment: Great!! Thanks Sheikh, is now working but it still shows |head for the get functions

Comment: It's just fine (HEAD), always welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest `dev` version. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106845/741747). The bug is not present on any stable release. Change your `composer.json`'s `minimum-stability` to `stable` and run a composer update. More on [this thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3733) on `Github`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append **get** method at the end of your query, in order to return collection. When you have collection (which is Laravel collection of objects) you will be able to call method on that objects.

Comment: Its not working and creates a problem on $user->count() function.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar symptoms, but in my case the problem was in the table schema definition:

```
        $table->integer('my_id')->unsigned();
```

Needed to be:

```
        $table->increments('my_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just had the same issue
but i couldnt go stable as @The Alpha suggested as it was running React.js and it required a dev edition

so here is how i solve it

instead of

```
>>> $note->body = 'Some note for the card.';
=> "Some note for the card."
>>> $note->card_id = 2;
=> 2
>>> $note->save();
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
  Call to undefined method stdClass::save()
```

here is what i did

```
>>> $note = new App\Note;
=> App\Note {#640}
>>> $note->body = 'Some note for the card.';
=> "Some note for the card."
>>> $note->card_id = 2;
=> 2
>>> $note->save();
=> true
```

and it worked ! Cheers