# blade template not working probably in Laravel 4.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

simply i tried to use the blade template system which comes with laravel framework but its not working for me
in views folder i have another folder called dashboard and have a simple view file called hello inside the dashboard folder
my routes file have this simple rule

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('dashboard.hello');
});
```

if the view file have the name hello.php it works fine and the view loaded without problem .
when i renamed the file to hello.blade.php the gives error and throw exception

```
ErrorException

mkdir(): No such file or directory (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\larvel\app\views\dashboard\hello.blade.php)
```

Comment: what should i do  ? :)
its a fresh installation of laravel nothing added yet

Comment: It could be a bug if this is a new installation of current `dev` version and you may try a stable version to make sure, similar (Bug for `dev` version) problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119138/laravel-dev-version-causes-call-to-undefined-method-stdclass/22121647#22121647).

Comment: @SheikhHeera no i don't use dev version i always use stable version and in my composer.json iset up minimum-stability to stable

Comment: @Marco is your view file located at `app/views/dashboard/hello.blade.php`?

Comment: The script is definitely loading the `C:\xampp\htdocs\larvel\app\views\dashboard\hello.blade.php` file, I would double and triple check that the file is named correctly and is in the correct path. Also, you misspelt the Laravel directory :)

Comment: @watcher i triple check the name its hello.blade.php

Answer (score -1):

Try with a / to separate directory

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('dashboard/hello');
});
```

It works for me on linux.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `.` as a directory seperator. Laravel supports and encourages this.