# Laravel Eloquent ORM returning stdClass instead of Model instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

When I query data with eloquent, it returns stdClass objects instead of an instance of my Model when using the `get()` function.

```
$userFind = User::find(1)
$userGet  = DB::table('users')
            ->where('users.id','=', 1)
            ->select('users.*')->get()[0]

echo get_class($userFind) // -> App\User
echo get_class($userGet) // -> stdClass
```

[Laravel Eloquent ORM returnig stdClass instead of actual Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105148/laravel-eloquent-orm-returnig-stdclass-instead-of-actual-model) reports the same problem but it is an old topic and the solution was just to come back to a previous version of Laravel.

Comment: `User` is Eloquent, `DB::table` is the Query Builder. The Query Builder won't return Eloquent models.

Comment: Try `$userGet  = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->first();`

Comment: @anyber then how can I get users as a Model instance and using the `WHERE` clause? @AndreasHunter thank you, but `first()` also returns a stdClass instance.

Comment: You need to use Eloquent. Eloquent uses the same methods that Query Builder does, so you can still use all of the same methods. `User::find(1);` is the same as `User::where('id', '=', 1)->select('*')->first();` From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent), `Since Eloquent models are query builders, you should review all of the methods available on the query builder. You may use any of these methods in your Eloquent queries.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you used `\DB::table('users')` which is independent from your models and code structure. It's like running a query directly on the database, laravel can't know that the result is a complete `User` with all it's fields.

use

```php
$userGet = \App\User::query()
    ->where('id','=', 1)
    ->get()[0]
echo get_class($userGet) // -> App\User

//or simply
$userGet = \App\User::query()
    ->where('id','=', 1)
    ->first()
echo get_class($userGet) // -> App\User
```

Comment: You don't need `query()`, Eloquent already extends the Query Builder.

Comment: @aynber no, you dont need it, but it helps with the IDEs and Eloquent tries exactly that when you call a method from `QueryBuilder`. in the end, it's technically faster to do it yourself ;)

Comment: @aynber and i said "tries" cause no matter the call `$this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters)` and no, `Eloquent\Model` doesn't extend `QueryBuilder`

Comment: Sorry, I meant it uses the same methods, rather than extending it.

Comment: The query method is helpful for building more complex queries with joins and groupBy and select and whatnot.

Comment: You are right, but in my case, I am fetching data from another already created database. How can I overcome this issue? thank you

Comment: @OmarFd define the database to use in the model  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections

Comment: I already did but I am still having the following error:
 "App\\Models\\User::getCountryIdAttribute(): Return value must be of type ?Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder, App\\Models\\Country returned"

____This is the query: Country::where('id', $this->attributes['country_id'])
            ->get()->first();

Comment: Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027401/return-value-must-be-of-type-illuminate-database-query-builder-app-models

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of using `get()`method. It's because of using `DB` facade.

If you query using model facade every objects will cast in to particular model object.

And the `get()`function will return an `Eloquent Collection` instead of a one Object.

```php
// this is a collection of users
$users = User::where('id', 1)->get();
```

So if you want a one object from that collection you can call `first()` after it.
( instead of calling the array index [0] ).

```php
// this one is ok too.
// but it's not recommended.
$user = User::where('id', 1)->get()[0];

// this is proper way
$user = User::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
```

And if you are sure that there is only one row matching your conditions you can call `first()` instead of `get()`.

```php
$user = User::where('id', 1)->first();
```