# Return value must be of type ?Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder, App\\Models\\ModelName returned

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to have the following response:

```
"user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "email": "john@mail.com",
        "phone_number": "12345678",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-09-02T08:57:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-02T08:57:07.000000Z",
        "country": {
                     "id": 1,
                     "name": "UK",
                     "phone_code": 44
                    } 
    }
```

Instead of:

```
"user": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "email": "omar.fd.du@gmail.com",
        "phone_number": "12345678",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2021-09-02T08:57:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-02T08:57:07.000000Z",
        "country_id": 1
    }
```

In order to do that, I am using a mutator function inside the User Model:

```
public function getCountryIdAttribute(): Builder|null
{
   return Country::where('id', $this->attributes['country_id'])
    ->get()
    ->first();
}
```

However, the countries table is already found in an external database which I set up its connection properly.

But I created the Country Model following this [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
/**
 * The database connection that should be used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $connection = 'my second db connection name';

/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'countries';

/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * The model's default values for attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $attributes = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'phone_code',
];
}
```

When I am trying to fetch the user I get the following error:

```
{
"error": [
    "App\\Models\\User::getCountryIdAttribute(): Return value must be of type ? 
    Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder, App\\Models\\Country returned"
],
"message": "Unhandled server exception",
"code": 500
}
```

I tried to explain my case as much as possible.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are saying in the function `getCountryIdAttribute` it returns `Builder | null`. When you do

```
   return Country::where('id', $this->attributes['country_id'])
    ->get()
    ->first();
```

It will return an instance of `Country` or `null`. To fix your problem you should update your return type to `Country | null`:

```
public function getCountryIdAttribute(): Country | null
{
   return Country::where('id', $this->attributes['country_id'])
    ->get()
    ->first();
}
```

---

Laravel provides ways to work with [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) that will greatly improve your code performance. In this case you can do:

```
public function country()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Country::class, 'country_id');
}
```

Then when fetching the `users` you can do:

```
$users = User::where(...)->with('country')->get();
```

This will prevent your code from having [N+1](https://medium.com/doctolib/understanding-and-fixing-n-1-query-30623109fe89#:%7E:text=TL%3BDR%3A%20The%20N%2B,%E2%80%9CHow%20to%20fix%20it%3F%E2%80%9D) problems.

Comment: Thank you, it was a stupid mistake suggest by the IDE that I didn't give much attention to. And thanks for the extra tips, that will definitely help as I'm new in Laravel development.